# DFS-R Server Concerns

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs, dfs-r

What happens when one DFS server goes ***offline*** or the connection between the two drops?  Specifically, what happens when an existing file is updated.

So I just stood up two Win2K12 R2 servers running DFS.  One in Washington office and one in or Texas office.  The WA DFS server is running DFS Namespaces and DFS Replication while the TX DFS server is running *only* DFS Replication.

If one server drops, are my users still able to access the stored data from the other server - just maybe slower because of the connection?  What happens if the network connection goes down between the sites?  Are users still able to access the data from their respective office servers?  What happens when a document is updated between two sites during an outage?  How does the file get updated?  Is there something I should have done differently?

I'm trying to identify problems with my setup so I can bring my solution to management and have answers when they ask.  This is a major project and I want to do it right, so if anybody has any advice or comments, I would appreciate it.

Thanx,
David